# SQL table change sequence

Tags: sql, delphi

I have a table displayed in DBGrid the sort order is based on a Sequence field and I want to be able to move an item up or down one place at a time. I have researched here and cannot find anything exactly like I need.

The problem comes when I disable the Sort order to make a change, the list reverts to the order in which the data was originally entered, so I have lost the item next in line.

This is what I have...

```
Folder  Sequence
----------------
Buttons   1
Thread    2  << Current Row
Cotton    3
Rags      4
```

On clicking the "MoveDown" button I want...

```
Folder  Sequence
----------------
Buttons   1
Cotton    2
Thread    3  << Current Row
Rags      4
```

But - when I remove the Sort order on Sequence I get the order I entered the items...

```
Folder  Sequence
----------------
Buttons   1
Cotton    2
Rags      4
Thread    3  << Current Row
```

So far my attempts are proving pretty cumbersome and involve loading the Rows into a listbox, shuffling them and then writing them back to the Table. Gotta be a better way, but it is beyond my current grasp of SQL.

Can someone please point me in the direction to go.

I don't want to trouble anyone too much if it is a difficult thing to do in SQL, as I can always stay with the listbox approach. If it is relatively simple to an SQL-expert, then I would love to see the SQL text.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution is based on the TDataSet being sorted by the `Sequence` field:

```
MyDataSet.Sort := 'Sequence';
```

And then swapping the `Sequence` field between the *current row* and the `Next` (down) / `Prior` (up) records e.g.:

```
type
  TDBMoveRecord = (dbMoveUp, dbMoveDown);

function MoveRecordUpDown(DataSet: TDataSet; const OrderField: string;
  const MoveKind: TDBMoveRecord): Boolean;
var
  I, J: Integer;
  BmStr: TBookmarkStr;
begin
  Result := False;
  with DataSet do
  try        
    DisableControls;
    J := -1;
    I := FieldByName(OrderField).AsInteger;
    BmStr := DataSet.Bookmark;
    try
      case MoveKind of
        dbMoveUp: Prior;
        dbMoveDown: Next;
      end;
      if ((MoveKind = dbMoveUp) and BOF) or ((MoveKind = dbMoveDown) and EOF) then
      begin
        Beep;
        SysUtils.Abort;
      end
      else
      begin
        J := DataSet.FieldByName(OrderField).AsInteger;
        Edit;
        FieldByName(OrderField).AsInteger := I;
        Post;
      end;
    finally
      Bookmark := BmStr;
      if (J <> -1) then
      begin
        Edit;
        FieldByName(OrderField).AsInteger := J;
        Post;
        Result := True;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    EnableControls;
  end;
end;
```

***Usage:***

```
MoveRecordUpDown(MyDataSet, 'Sequence', dbMoveDown);    
// or     
MoveRecordUpDown(MyDataSet, 'Sequence', dbMoveUp);
```

Comment: if `Sequence` is set as table's `PRIMARY KEY`, wouldn't this violate that constraint and raise an exception??

Comment: @LightBulb, PKs are not meant to be changed at all. setting an index to `Sequence` however would be just fine.

Comment: @kobik thanks for going to so much detail, I appreciate it very much. The process is a lot more complicated than I had imagined and now I can see why I was struggling with it.

Comment: LB: This field, "Sequence," as Kobik surmised, is an ordinary field and not a Primary Key field, so there is no risk, but thanks for the caution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand right, you want to find "next sequence item"? 
May be you may do something like "get first min value, grater then X"?
In this way, you can pass prev. Row sequence value.